# How can i save images in sub directory in media?

Tags: django

in first step i have primary key in user field,then in second step in complete info in site image save,i want to uplaod image in this path:

```
/photos/user_id/file.png
```

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    personal_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='',blank=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

i want to upload image in sub directory that name is user_id

Comment: Would the name of the directory literally be "user_id" or would it be the user's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) can be given a *callable* as value, so you can define a function that specifies where to upload the file to:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    def personal_image_filename(self, filename):
        return f'photos/{self.user_id}/{filename}'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    personal_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=personal_image_filename,blank=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```